# cant checkout external git repo in jenkins

Tags: git, ssh, openshift

I have jenkins on openshift. I can do following and it works.

```
[jenkins-<USER>.rhcloud.com data]\> ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /var/lib/openshift/<NUMBERED DIRECTORY>/app-root/data/.ssh/jenkins_id_rsa git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi <USER>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
          Connection to github.com closed.
```

So it does connect to github...even I cloned it worked from shell.

But when I try to add repo to a jenkins job it gives following error. Its a private repo.

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@github.com:<USER>/test.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is probably running as `jenkins` and you accepted the host key for `<USER>` you can confirm this by adding the command `whoami` to your build steps and confirm the user in `jenkins` is different from the one in the shell.

One solution is to login as `jenkins` and accept the the key for github.

Another is to copy the line from ~/.ssh/known_hosts of github and copy it to the known_hosts in the jenkins folder ~jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts.

Comment: on openshift , known_hosts is not editable. Also, jenkins is built-in did not build.

Comment: ok, then [disable strick host checking](http://debuggable.com/posts/disable-strict-host-checking-for-git-clone:49896ff3-0ac0-4263-9703-1eae4834cda3) might help